# Incorrect syntax near 'SDFSDFJDH'. t-sql when extra ' is coming in insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-insert

When I'm trying to insert any data in field with DataType as NVARCHAR(MAX) and data contains some "'", then it is giving error every time...

Please suggest.

I want to insert here as **Yesterday i went Roshan's b'day**

here is my query

```
INSERT INTO TEST1242 VALUES(1,'Yesterday i went Roshan's b'day')
```

Error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 's'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are directly running it on the RDBMS, you need to double the single quote,

```
INSERT INTO TEST1242 VALUES(1,'Yesterday i went Roshan''s b''day')
```

but if on the application level, better to parameterized the value to avoid from `SQL Injection`.